Post title ignoring context and patterns not working with provided postId and postType context in render
I've setup a basic block that needs to pass down the context of a post to its innerBlocks similar to how the query block does, so that the title, featured image and excerpt blocks work off that new post and not the current page. I'm doing this so I can make use of the same pattern for a "tease" in both query blocks and elsewhere on the site.
I've set this up with a basic useSelect to get all the posts of the type I'm after and am storing the postType and postId attributes. My block.json has providesContext setup and this is correctly passing the context to my test block in the front end and back end. On thsi back end this all seems to work fully with the exception of excerpts not loading, But I'm having some weird issues on the front end I can't work out.
If i add a featured image, excerpt block or published date block, the context is correctly passed and the right image and content loads. But if I add a post-title block, this does not work.
If I make a synced pattern that contains the same set of blocks, none of them work.
I had initially thought that as post-title was using get_the_title() and not making use of it's context I'd need to also setup postdata in my render.php so I added this, but even that doesn't seem to work to setup post data at all.
<?php
$newPost = get_post($attributes['postId']);
setup_postdata( $newPost );
?>
<div <?php echo get_block_wrapper_attributes(); ?>>
    <?php echo get_the_title(); ?>
    <?php echo $content; ?>
</div>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

Is my approach here wrong? I can't seem to find much online at all on the subject and the docs are really no help.
I've been trying to debug this and I setup a basic test block that consumes the postId and postType context, this works fine front and back end. But when in a synced pattern that is placed inside this provider block it only gets the postId and postType for the page it is on and not the one from the context.

In your render.php, the get_post() function is passed "null", so it retrieves the default post objects title. To resolve your issue, pass $newPost to get_post() to get a specific post title, eg:
render.php
<?php
$newPost = get_post($attributes['postId']);
setup_postdata( $newPost );
?>
<div <?php echo get_block_wrapper_attributes(); ?>>
    <?php echo get_the_title($newPost); ?>
    <?php echo $content; ?>
</div>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

As a side note, I've previously converted a "featured post" short code into a block, close to the "teaser" concept you describe (a while back now, before block patterns). My approach was similar with the SelectControl in  edit.js to select and store the postId as a block attribute. In render.php (or render_callback function) I used a new WP_Query to retrieve the post and feed the post meta into blocks using do_blocks() to render the block content.
Updated Answer for WP 3.7.1
At present, the core/post-title block does not contain the $post object like the post-excerpt and featured-image blocks, which is why they both work recieve the postId context within innerBlocks and post-title does not.
The logic goes that the core/post-title block is to be used within the loop context. I suggest creating a custom variation of the query-loop with your desired pattern so the post title resides inside the query loop. In your variation, define the postType and any other query parameters as needed.

I was only using get_the_title() in my code here as this is what the core/post-title block does, they specifically don;t pass the context postId to the function for some editor reasons. Using get_the_title after having setup post data should return the correct title as the post data should be setup, but this appears to not work inside blocks.

Yes, the core/post-title block does it that way to enable post preview The post title block uses "usesContext": [ "postId", "postType", "queryId" ] which its still inheriting from the main query unless you add it. I set up a basic dynamic block with the render.php above and it produces the correct title from the postId attribute. By not working in blocks, do you mean InnerBlocks in the editor &/or rendering the content dynamically front end?

Everything works perfectly in the editor. It's only the front end having issues.
All this block does is provide context for postId and postType. Inside its inner blocks I've added all the basic blocks that consume those such as title, featured image, date and except. I've also added my own test block that consumes these and displays the postId and postType. I've also taken all of those blocks, created a synced pattern and added this along with the the same blocks. All the blocks but the title work on the front end inside the inner blocks, but all the patterns blocks don't work.

@ChrisMorris Which version of WordPress are you testing with and do you have the latest Gutenberg plugin also installed as well?

6.7.1 so I've not got the plugin installed.

@ChrisMorris Thanks, I've updated the answer and hope it helps resolve your issue.
